# JAX-RS UriInfo.getQueryParameters() returns UnmodifiableMultivaluedMap

Tags: java, jax-rs

I am using `JAX-RS` to create RESTful web services. 
I have created an API which is like this:

```
GET /articles?userId=<userId>
```

UI makes call to this API and passes the **encoded** `userId`, for example like this:

```
GET /articles?userId=dGVzdA
```

In Back-end I've created Filter which takes all the `QueryParam`-s (userId in this case), checks if it's valid, decodes it and passes to `Controller`.

```
public class MyFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) {

        MultivaluedMap<String, String> queryParams = requestContext.getUriInfo().getQueryParameters();

        //Checking if it's valid, decoding and some other stuff
        ....


        queryParams.replace("userId", decodedUserId);
    }
}
```

After upgrading `JAX-RS` version to 2.0 I found out that the `requestContext.getUriInfo().getQueryParameters()` returns `UnmodifiableMultivaluedMap` instead of `MultivaluedMap`.

So when I'm calling `replace` or `put` on `UnmodifiableMultivaluedMap` I'm getting `UnsupportedOperationException`, because it's **"unmodifiable"**.

So Is it possible to modify `UnmodifiableMultivaluedMap`? or maybe there is  another way to achieve this?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: In the request, the QueryParam comes as encoded, so I have to decode it and pass to the controller. Otherwise I should decode it in each controller.

Comment: That's our requirement for security.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `UriBuilder` object returned by `requestContext.getUriInfo().getRequestUriBuilder()` method call. It has all the methods you need.
Ex:- 
`matrixParam(String name, Object... values)` 
 `buildFromMap(Map<String,?> values)`